# disable input field when is not empty and enable it if is empty not working

Tags: javascript

disable input text area  when not null and enable when null not  working text area is disabled only

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#note").val() !== = '') {
    $("#note").prop("disabled", true);
  } else($("#note").val() === '') {
    $("#note").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Comment: did you have a question or specific problem you would like to address? (besides the `!== =` syntax problem?)

Comment: Do you realize that only runs on page load? If will not update?

Comment: thank you  code working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the condition from the `else` statement and correct the `!==` comparison:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#note").val() !==  '') {
    $("#note").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#note").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Comment: if section condition  Applied to if section and else section

Comment: The else itself doesn’t need a condition, if you need a condition you can use else if.

Comment: I’m glad I have been helpful